# Best way to pass variables between Arduino and PC over serial?

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, bit-manipulation

I've written an Arduino sketch which reads data from a remote control receiver and returns a value between 0 and 1023 for that channel. I basically want to send this data (something in the format of channel:value, eg, Channel 1 : 1023, Channel 2 : 511) to a PC program (which I plan to write myself).

The most efficient way I can think to do this is to use two bytes of data, with the first 6 bits representing the channel (2^6 = 64 possible channels, way more than I need), and the last ten representing the value (2^10 = 1024, perfect). But I'm not sure on the best way to implement this in C++, or if this is even the most ideal way to do this. So:

1. What is the best way to craft individual bytes and work with binary numbers in C++? Preferably storing the values in memory as such (ie, no bool arrays, where each index takes up it's own byte). Two bytes of data is more than enough for what I need.
2. Is this the easiest/simplest/most efficient/recommended way to implement what I am trying to achieve? I basically want to pass variables as is between programs, are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a packed `struct` to hold these two values:

```
struct chan_value_t
{
  uint8_t  channel : 6;
  uint16_t value   : 10;
};
```

But to send it as two bytes, you'll need to either (1) "union" it with a two-byte array:

```
union chan_value_t
{
  struct {
    uint8_t  channel : 6;
    uint16_t value   : 10;
  };
  uint8_t bytes[2];
};

chan_value_t cv;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin( 9600 );

  cv.channel = 2;
  cv.value = 800;
  for (int i=0; i<sizeof(cv.bytes); i++) {
    Serial.print( cv.bytes[i], HEX );
    Serial.print( ' ' );
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {}
```

(The `struct` is anonymous when nested in this union; the union has the name.)

Or (2) cast a pointer to the struct to a pointer to bytes:

```
struct chan_value_t {
  uint8_t  channel : 6;
  uint16_t value   : 10;
};

chan_value_t cv;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin( 9600 );

  cv.channel = 2;
  cv.value = 800;
  uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *) &cv; // cast &cv to a pointer to bytes
  for (int i=0; i<sizeof(cv); i++) {
    Serial.print( bytes[i], HEX );
    Serial.print( ' ' );
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {}
```

They both print the hexadecimal value of the bytes: 0x02 and 0xC8.  800 is 0x320, shifted left by 6 bits is 0xC800.

To send this to the PC, you may want to start with a special character sequence and finish with a checksum of some sort (Fletcher checksum is easy).  Then it's easy to throw away garbage characters and know when there are transmission errors.

Comment: Ok, so I would use bit fields, create a union with a byte array, and then read the data "through" the byte array?

I haven't used bit fields before, so to clarify, if I declare something like int myInt : 6, that will define an integer with 2^6 possible values? Same with 2^10?

Comment: Ok so I've implemented this on my end, but I'm getting unexpected behaviour. The bytes seem to be printed and read correctly, so it's _most likely_ not a problem with how I've implemented this solution, but elsewhere in my code. Just to help troubleshooting, are there any gotchas with this I should know about? Eg, is there any bit-shifting I have to do when assigning variables, are the members not packed right next to each other in memory, etc?

Comment: Additionally, for the checksum, I've just XORed the two bytes together (I figured that would be the simplest for two bytes of data). Any advice on if that is a good method?

Comment: There's nothing special about using the struct members.  The compiler generates all the code to do the shifting and masking for you.  However, the XOR checksum is not very good.  GPS NMEA sentences use it, and it can catch a single bit error, but not multiple bit errors.  For example if the same character is dropped twice, and XOR checksum will still pass.  Or if the same bit is toggled in any two characters, it will pass.  :(  That's why I suggested Fletcher: it's easy and very efficient.  TCP uses it, too.

Comment: Great! I'll go through some debugging tonight and work out what the issue is, and implement a more robust checksum.

Comment: Awesome, got it working! Turns out the function was fine, it was just being passed junk data from elsewhere in my program. Sorted that out, works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

This is aimed at your no. 2 question.

OSC (OpenSoundControl) is a convenient way to send messages across different platforms and devices. Libraries exist for most platforms.

You could use the library [OSC for Arduino](http://cnmat.berkeley.edu/oscuino) and implement your own solution to the [specification](http://opensoundcontrol.org/spec-1_0) or using a library that fits your context.

The message you mention could be sent as /channel/1 /value/1023

Comment: OSC seems a little heavy-weight for what he's doing.  OSC uses heap memory via `new/malloc` and `delete/free`, which can be troublesome in limited-RAM environments like the Arduino.  Also, the message would be a more verbose text string (24 bytes?) instead of a short binary packet (6 bytes?).

Comment: Yeah it does seem a little heavyweight, but it's good to know about alternatives I have available, esprcially when there seem to be readymade libraries for it.